# Rails Modules: How to define instance methods inside a class method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, module, metaprogramming

I'd like to create a module called StatusesExtension that defines a has_statuses method. When a class extends StatusesExtension, it will have validations, scopes, and accessors for on those statuses. Here's the module:

```
module StatusesExtension
  def has_statuses(*status_names)
    validates :status, presence: true, inclusion: { in: status_names }

    # Scopes
    status_names.each do |status_name|
      scope "#{status_name}", where(status: status_name)
    end

    # Accessors
    status_names.each do |status_name|
      define_method "#{status_name}?" do
        status == status_name
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Here's an example of a class that extends this module:

```
def Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend StatusesExtension
  has_statuses :unanswered, :answered, :ignored
end
```

The problem I'm encountering is that while scopes are being defined, the instance methods (answered?, unanswered?, and ignored?) are not. For example:

```
> Question.answered
=> [#<Question id: 1, ...>]
> Question.answered.first.answered?
=> false # Should be true
```

How can I use modules to define both class methods (scopes, validations) and instance methods (accessors) within the context of a single class method (has_statuses) of a module?

Thank you!

Comment: They are being defined, just not right. If you get a result other than NoMethodError, the method has been defined.

Comment: Works for me: https://gist.github.com/jimmycuadra/5529912

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the comments have said, the method is being defined, just not working as expected.  I suspect this is because you are comparing a string with a symbol within the method (`status_names` is an array of symbols, and `status` will be a string).  Try the following:

```ruby
status_names.each do |status_name|
  define_method "#{status_name}?" do
    status == status_name.to_s
  end
end
```

Comment: This works, thanks a lot! I noticed that my attempt to set the STATUS default value to a symbol in my POSTGRES migration actually made it a string. ("unanswered" instead of :unanswered)... Do you know of a way to set symbols as defaults in migrations? My attempt: "add_column :questions, :status, :string, default: :unanswered"

Comment: Symbols are a Ruby thing, and therefore don't relaly make sense oustide a ruby context, like in a database.  Your database will always hold string values.